# Working on a tone generator program. The 'duration' variable (in seconds) doesn't correctly determine how long the tone plays for

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyaudio

Here's what I've got. The duration variable is set to play the tone for 4 seconds, but when the code is run, it only plays for about 1.5 seconds. I've sorta hit a wall with this one; any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import pyaudio
import numpy as np

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

volume = 0.5     # range [0.0, 1.0]
fs = 44100       # sampling rate, Hz, must be integer
duration = 4.0   # in seconds, may be float
f = 440.0        # sine frequency, Hz, may be float

# generate samples, note conversion to float32 array
samples = (np.sin(2*np.pi*np.arange(fs*duration)*f/fs)).astype(np.float32)

# for paFloat32 sample values must be in range [-1.0, 1.0]
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
                channels=1,
                rate=fs,
                output=True)

# play. May repeat with different volume values (if done interactively) 
stream.write(volume*samples)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()

p.terminate()
```

Comment: btw, you should try to avoid all the copies during the initialization of `samples`. Also note that a single call to `stream.write` is not interruptible.

Answer (score 2):

Something appears to be buggy with the array-size detection of `stream.write`. I'm guessing it divides by the format size when it shouldn't.

Calling `stream.write(volume*samples, len(samples))` works for me.